# Multiple xml files transform using java to html file

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My question is simple
I have two xml files and one xsl file using java Transformer I needed to create html stringbuffer. I know how to deal with single xml file I need help to using two xmls.

My first xml

xml_1.xml(data xml)

```
<data>  
      <title>Mr</title>
      <name>Peter</name>
</data>
```

And my second xml is

xml_2.xml(property xml)

```
<prop>
       <lblname>Name</lblname>
       <lbltitle>Title</lbltitle>
</prop>
```

And my xsl is

dispaly.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;"><!ENTITY bull "&#x2022;">]>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="prop/lbltitle" /></td>
            <td width="1"><xsl:value-of select="prop/lblname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="data/title" /></td>
            <td width="1"><xsl:value-of select="data/namee" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</xsl:template>
```

What I need is using java make transform this in to html file and here is the sample code I used for single xml file,

Java sample code

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

            Writer outWriter = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**What I need is using java make transform this in to html file and here is the sample code I used for single xml file,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `document()` function to access multiple documents during the transformation. For convenience, the solution below stores the documents in variables because they are used more than once.

Note that

- since you are obviously producing HTML, you should set the `output` method to "html"
- there was a typo in your stylesheet, an element with the name `namee` does not exist in the XML input
- the resulting table does not qualify as a complete HTML document. You should be aware of that if you intend to use it as such
- the `colspan` attributes of some of your `td` elements do not make sense. It is of use only if, in another row, there are *more* table cells that can be spanned

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;"><!ENTITY bull "&#x2022;">]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="data" select="document('data.xml')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="property" select="document('property.xml')"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
           <tr>
               <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="$property/prop/lbltitle" /></td>
               <td width="1"><xsl:value-of select="$property/prop/lblname" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="$data/data/title" /></td>
               <td width="1"><xsl:value-of select="$data/data/name" /></td>
           </tr>
         </table>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Title</td>
      <td width="1">Name</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Mr</td>
      <td width="1">Peter</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```